# Where can I find the Blog Post HTML?

Tags: templates

I am new to Joomla and am having some difficulties. I have been asked to work on a site for someone and I need to adjust the HTML on their Blog post page (the page that lists all the blog posts whit their intro text and intro images).

Looking in the index.php of the template (which is the only HTML file in the template folder) I dont see any mention of the blog page.

Would anyone be able to help me out and point me in the right direction here? Should I be looking in Joomla's layouts directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout for Category Blog is actually is defined in this file :

```
../components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.php
```

If you open the file, you will see this file will call these child layouts :

```
../components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php
../components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_links.php
../components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_children.php
```

So, basically you can change the layout for blog layout by modifying those files above.

But, it is NOT recommended to modify those files directly because any change you made on those files will be overwritten when a Joomla update is installed in the future.

So, how to deal with it?
Joomla has a template override features that allows you to override visual output of any extension you have. You can read the fully explanation [here](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) but in your case above, you just need to copy those files above to :

```
../templates/your_template_name/html/com_content/category/blog.php
../templates/your_template_name/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php
../templates/your_template_name/html/com_content/category/blog_links.php
../templates/your_template_name/html/com_content/category/blog_children.php
```

and modify it. 
If the folder 'html' doesn't exist on your template, simply create it.